# Changing Pixels in a PyTorch Image

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting started with PyTorch. I have loaded CIFAR10 and would now like to manually play around with the images a bit (ultimately, I am interested in certain augmentations for contrastive learning). However, I can't even set individual pixels to zero. What is going wrong in below code? It doesn't change the entries of the tensor.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)

indices_train = [i for i in range(len(trainset)) if trainset.targets[i] in [1,2]]
trainset = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainset, indices_train)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

print(trainset[0][0][:,1,1])
trainset[0][0][:,1,1] = 0
print(trainset[0][0][:,1,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html).
The goal of a dataset is to load the data from the disk.

When you do:

```
trainset[0][0][:,1,1] = 0
# is more equivalent to
image_label = getimage(0) # trainset[0]
image = image_label[0]    # trainset[0][0]
image[:,1,1] = 0          # trainset[0][0][:,1,1]
```

Where the function (actually `Dataset.__getitem__`) looks very simplified like this:

```
#trainset[0]
def getimage(index): # this is the __getitem__ function of a dataset
    image = load_from_disk(image_files[index]) # e.g. via Pillow
    label = get_class(index)
    return Tensor(image), label
```

That means every time you access `trainset[0]` the files are loaded again freshly from the disk - that is why you cannot modify them like this.

You would have to do the following to see the effect:

```
image, label = trainset[0]
print(image)
image[:,1,1] = 0
print(image)
```

---

This is the official example how you could write your own function:
See also [TorchVison Cifar10Dataset](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/cifar.html#CIFAR10)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.io import read_image

# this is inside a dataset class

class CustomDataset(torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10):

# The parent class handles ass the variables here
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #MNIST is kept in memory and is accesses like this:
        img, target = self.data[index], self.targets[index]

        img = Image.fromarray(img)

        # Apply augmentations
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        if self.target_transform is not None:
            target = self.target_transform(target)

        # Apply some custom augmentations appart from the transforms pipeline:
        img[:,1,1] = 0

        return img, target


#this is the basic toch.utils.data.Dataset way:
    def getitem_from_disk(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1] # need to loaded with a custom(!) __init__ function

        # Apply augmentations
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But then, how can I proceed to include the changed images into trainset? Just setting
trainset[i] = image, label will not work, right?

Comment: Yes it will not work. I modified my post a little. Transformations are handled inside the get function - therefore they are not permanent. If you want permanent changes you would need to save the image and load it explicitly again.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I am a bit lost. Where exactly do I include this in the code?

Comment: I completed the class to be usable with CIFAR10, you need only the `__getitem__` the `getitem_from_disk` is the way how you could write your own fully customizable dataset. In general do you apply the augmentations via the `transforms` parameter and adding transformations to the `Compose` (augmentation) pipeline - this way you do not need to create your own dataset class. Hope it is clearer now